# Split words from `read` and store to array?

Tags: shell, array, read

How can I take input from `read`, split the words up by spaces, and then put those words into an array?

What I want is:

```
$ read sentence
this is a sentence
$ echo $sentence[1]
this
$ echo $sentence[2]
is
(and so on...)
```

I'm using this to process English sentences for a text adventure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using `bash`, its `read` command has a `-a` option for that.

From `help read`

```
Options:
  -a array  assign the words read to sequential indices of the array
        variable ARRAY, starting at zero
```

So

```
$ read -a s
This is a sentence.
```

Note that the resulting array is zero indexed, so

```
$ echo "${s[0]}"
This
$ echo "${s[1]}"
is
$ echo "${s[2]}"
a
$ echo "${s[3]}"
sentence.
$
```

Answer (score 1):

A similar response to that of @steeldriver

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "Input text:" && read UI ;
read -a UIS <<< ${UI} ;
X=0 ;
for iX in ${UIS[*]} ; do printf "position: ${X}==${iX}\n" ; ((++X)) ; done ;
```