# How to identify the number of column in a file just like Python enumerate?

Tags: bash, awk

Sample file:

```
11:34:21.590434 IP 10.10.1.30 > 10.10.1.217: ICMP echo reply, id 27948, seq 1, length 64
```

In Python, it's easy to identify the number of field by using enumerate function. E.g.

```
>>> i = '11:34:21.590434 IP 10.10.1.30 > 10.10.1.217: ICMP echo reply, id 27948, seq 1, length 64'
>>>
```

Split the string

```
>>> i.split()
['11:34:21.590434', 'IP', '10.10.1.30', '>', '10.10.1.217:', 'ICMP', 'echo', 'reply,', 'id', '27948,', 'seq', '1,', 'length', '64']
>>>
```

Put it on new variable, let say `j`

```
>>> j = i.split()
>>>
```

Enumerate it

```
>>> for i in enumerate(j, 1): i
... 
(1, '11:34:21.590434')
(2, 'IP')
(3, '10.10.1.30')
(4, '>')
(5, '10.10.1.217:')
(6, 'ICMP')
(7, 'echo')
(8, 'reply,')
(9, 'id')
(10, '27948,')
(11, 'seq')
(12, '1,')
(13, 'length')
(14, '64')
>>>
```

So, if I want to print out the source IP which is field number 3 with awk, it's so easy rather than to identify it manually with naked eyes.

```
wolf@linux:~$ awk '{print $3}' file.txt 
10.10.1.30
wolf@linux:~$
```

I know it's possible to do similar thing in Linux/Bash, I just can't figure it out yet.

**Update**

I know it's easy to get the number of column by using `NF`

```
wolf@linux:~$ awk '{ print NF }' file.txt
14
wolf@linux:~$
```

But what I want to achieve here is to identify each column and it's numbers. Probably something similar like Python enumerate output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split words from \`read\` and store to array?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/284245/split-words-from-read-and-store-to-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate the fields using AWK:

```
awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) print i, $i }' file.txt
```

or with `tr` and `nl`:

```
tr ' ' '\n' < file.txt | nl
```

(Filter through `head -n1` first if you want to stop at the end of the first line with `tr`; otherwise fields will be counted across lines.)

You can also find this out using Bash arrays (depending on `IFS`):

```
arr=($(head -n1 file.txt))
i=0
while [[ i -lt ${#arr[@]} ]]; do
    printf "%d %s\n" $((i+1)) "${arr[$i]}"
    ((i++))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for multi-char `RS` and `\s` shorthand for `[[:space:]]`:

```
$ awk -v RS='\\s+' '{print NR, $0}' file
1 11:34:21.590434
2 IP
3 10.10.1.30
4 >
5 10.10.1.217:
6 ICMP
7 echo
8 reply,
9 id
10 27948,
11 seq
12 1,
13 length
14 64
```

It assumes you only have 1 line in your input just like in the example in your question.

Comment: Thanks, but I did not get similar output ...

`wolf@linux:~$ awk -v RS='\\s+' '{print NR, $0}' file.txt 
1 11:34:21.590434 IP 10.10.1.30 > 10.10.1.217: ICMP echo reply, id 27948, 
2 eq 1, length 64 

wolf@linux:~$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
wolf@linux:~$ 
`

Comment: Then you copy/pasted wrong, or you aren't using gawk as the answer says is required, or your input doesn't look like the line you posted. If you use the script I posted on the input you posted using gawk as I said is required then you WILL get the output I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
$ tr ' ' '\n' < file.txt | nl
     1  11:34:21.590434
     2  IP
     3  10.10.1.30
     4  >
     5  10.10.1.217:
     6  ICMP
     7  echo
     8  reply,
     9  id
    10  27948,
    11  seq
    12  1,
    13  length
    14  64
$
```

or

```
$ read -ab < file.txt 
$ for c in ${b[*]}; do echo $c; done | nl
     1  11:34:21.590434
     2  IP
     3  10.10.1.30
     4  >
     5  10.10.1.217:
     6  ICMP
     7  echo
     8  reply,
     9  id
    10  27948,
    11  seq
    12  1,
    13  length
    14  64
$
```

Answer (score 0):

I guessed there are not any right solution rather than [Stephen Kitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/631877/60575).
but if you only need *IP Addrerss* you could use below

```
tr ' ' '\n' <<<'11:34:21.590434 IP 10.10.1.30 > 10.10.1.217: ICMP echo reply, id 27948, seq 1, length 64' | grep IP -A1 | grep -v IP
```

Answer (score 0):

grep out the fields and lay them one per line. Then number them with grep's -n option.

```
echo "....." |
grep -Po  '\S+' | grep -n ^ | sed 's/:/ /'
```

or

```
cat file.txt | grep -Po  '\S+' | grep -n ^ | sed 's/:/ /'
```

---

For perls more recent than 5.14.4

```
perl -lane '
  while (my($i,$e) = each @F) { print "$i $e"; }
' file.input
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with `sed`

```
$ sed -n '/1/{s/ /\n/g;p}' < file.txt | nl
     1  11:34:21.590434
     2  IP
     3  10.10.1.30
     4  >
     5  10.10.1.217:
     6  ICMP
     7  echo
     8  reply,
     9  id
    10  27948,
    11  seq
    12  1,
    13  length
    14  64
       
$
```